# SWRevealViewController затемнение основного ViewController'a

Tags: ios, objective-c, library, swift4

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи стека!

Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо реализовать при открытии бокового меню затемнение основного ViewController'a, при этом UI элементы на данном ViewController'ре работать также не должны, за исключением "бургера". Реализовать все нужно в классе SWRevealViewController, да бы не засорять свои ViewController'ы "мусором", что вызывает дополнительные сложности, так как SWRevealViewController написан на Objective-C, а с ним я ранее дел не имел.

В силу своих не знаний, для реализации и приобретения бесценного опыта прошу поддержки в решении данной задачи. Ниже прилагаю примерный макет в виде картинки.

Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся!

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Решал задачу как у вас. Релизация была следующая: в каждом контроллере в методе делегата создавал UIView на весь экран и делал его полупрозрачным. Ну и так-же скрывал UIView. Есть код если интересно данное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого ViewController который есть в меню добавляем:

```
@interface ViewController () <SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView* holderView;


#pragma mark - SWRevealViewController
        - (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {
            if (position == FrontViewPositionRight) {
                self.holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
                self.holderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                self.holderView.alpha = 0;
                [self.view addSubview:self.holderView];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                    self.holderView.alpha = 0.1;
                }];

            }
            else if (position == FrontViewPositionLeft){
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                    self.holderView.alpha = 0;
                    [self.holderView removeFromSuperview];
                }];
            }
        }
```